# R: Soft code rbind within a loop

Tags: arrays, r, loops, rbind

I have a large

```
GbyEbyA<-array(NA,c(50,1,10,900))
```

of data and I would like to soft code this so that if i change the third dimension of my array the loop will adjust (e.g. if I change from 10 environments to 5).

```
comb<-list()
for(i in 1:length(acc)){
comb[[i]]<-rbind(GbyEbyA[,,1,i],GbyEbyA[,,2,i],GbyEbyA[,,3,i],GbyEbyA[,,4,i],GbyEbyA[,,5,i],
                 GbyEbyA[,,6,i],GbyEbyA[,,7,i],GbyEbyA[,,8,i],GbyEbyA[,,9,i],GbyEbyA[,,10,i])
}
```

Is there a way to soft code this to something like this example (obviously this does not work):

```
comb<-list()
for(i in 1:length(acc)){
comb[[i]]<-rbind(get(paste("GbyEbyA[,,",1:10,",",i,"]",sep="")))
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is very un-R, but could you nest another loop?  Something like this?

```
for(i in 1:length(acc){
   for(j in 1:10){
       comb[[i]]<-rbind(GbyEbyA[,,j,i])
   }
}
```